# How to store AES_encrypt size cipher with exact size calculation?

Tags: c, encryption, cryptography, aes, caesar-cipher

I am facing issues with AES encryption text and need a bit help regarding the same ,here is a explanation ,I am using this function to convert a plain text to cipher text.

```
/*
 * Encrypt *len bytes of data
 * All data going in & out is considered binary (unsigned char[])
 */
unsigned char *aes_encrypt(EVP_CIPHER_CTX *e, unsigned char *plaintext, int *len)
{
  /* max ciphertext len for a n bytes of plaintext is n + AES_BLOCK_SIZE -1 bytes */
  int c_len = *len + AES_BLOCK_SIZE, f_len = 0;
  unsigned char *ciphertext = palloc(c_len);

  /* allows reusing of 'e' for multiple encryption cycles */
  EVP_EncryptInit_ex(e, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL);

  /* update ciphertext, c_len is filled with the length of ciphertext generated,
    *len is the size of plaintext in bytes */
  EVP_EncryptUpdate(e, ciphertext, &c_len, plaintext, *len);

  /* update ciphertext with the final remaining bytes */
  EVP_EncryptFinal_ex(e, ciphertext+c_len, &f_len);

  *len = c_len + f_len;
  return ciphertext;
}
```

This function works perfectly when we use encryption but when i try to calculate length of cipher-text using strlen i don't get exact length , 
i have google and found a bit information regarding cipher-text printing in for 
loop using %c equal to a length of size len.

my query is how would i store cipher text either in a file with the exact length ? as strlen(cipher-text) doesn't give exact length ,what is a way to store cipher text ?

Any help would be much appreciated :) Thanks in advance

Comment: What cipher mode are you using?

Comment: Your last two sentences were included in the code block because you did not add an empty line between them.

Comment: @luke i am using EVP_aes_256_cbc() with AES_BLOCK_SIZE 256 block size

Comment: `AES_BLOCK_SIZE` is always 16, never 256

Comment: caesar-cipher is the wrong tag ..

Comment: Also, weird: you have no key, nor iv in EVP_EncryptInit_ex, and no cipher type.
Are these initialised elsewhere?

Comment: @henno ,yes internally i am calculating length  based on 16 block size,no those are not initialized ,i have referred a code from google

Comment: Don’t just copy code. Understand what’s happening.

Comment: The size could increase by a full AES_BLOCK_SIZE

Comment: please find a git code i am referring to : https://github.com/saju/misc/blob/master/misc/openssl_aes.c

Comment: You do not check the return value of `palloc`, always check return values..

Comment: The signature or API for `aes_encrypt` is incorrect. You are discarding the cipher text length information. You have to return the length in addition to the `unsigned char *`. Related, see [EVP Symmetric Encryption and Decryption](https://wiki.openssl.org/index.php/EVP_Symmetric_Encryption_and_Decryption) on the OpenSSL wiki.

Comment: Instead of returning a `unsigned char*` maybe you need to return a structure that includes both the cipher text and the length. [ASN.1](https://www.itu.int/en/ITU-T/asn1/Pages/introduction.aspx) or [BSON](http://bsonspec.org/) might be helpful for you. They are just presentation formats, like Hex or Base64 encoding.

Answer (score 1):

The whole point of this interface is that `*len` now contains the length of the ciphertext (I suppose it starts with the value of the plain text). The EncryptFinal adds padding, so that the lengths are changed. If plain has length 16
the ciphertext will have length 32.

You cannot use `strlen` to compute the lengths. This can be done in the case of the `argv` entries, as these are strings by design. The `key` is more like a password here. It's a pretty encryption weak system (hard coded salt, 5 rounds etc.).

After `ciphertext = aes_encrypt(&en, (unsigned char *)input[i], &len);`
if you want to write the ciphertext to file, just do something like

```
 FILE *cipher = NULL; 
 cipherfile=fopen("mycipher.txt", "wb"); 
 if (NULL ==cipherfile){ /* error handling here */
 }
 if (1 != fwrite(ciphertext, len, 1, cipherfile)){ /* error handling */
 }
 close(cipherfile);
```

because the ciphertext length is in `len`. The original author [at GitHub](https://github.com/saju/misc/blob/master/misc/openssl_aes.c) probably intended `olen` to be used instead (now it's unused). So (better) `&olen` can be used in both calls (`aes_encrypt` and `fwrite`) above, and then `len` stays the input length, which can be used in decryption checking, etc.

Comment: Thanks for letting me ,it works but ,i have a issue with storing cipher with files due to security issue , is so what i want is to store a cipher text into a database without storing and reading back and forth from a file ,do you know a better way to store a text cipher and lets assume database uses string function (like strcpy / strlen ) to store a cipher ,that is a reason i am not able to store a cipher text into a memory ,do you know any other way to achieve it ,would be helpful. Thanks in advance for a help till now ,really appreciate it .

Comment: @Gaurav if data is encrypted, what’s the issue with storing it in a file? If you need to store it as a string, just hexify it and unhexify before decrypting. Or use base64, which is more efficient but a bit more complex.